# Adding pages/posts after plugin installation

Tags: wordpress

There are a few plugins that I know that after installation they will create pages or posts. How do you do this?

Tried to research but could not find helpful guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) reference on the WordPress Codex might help.

Here's an example code of how to create a new post programmatically:

```
// Create post object
  $my_post = array(
     'post_title' => 'My post',
     'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_author' => 1,
     'post_category' => array(8,39)
  );

// Insert the post into the database
  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

To run this code automatically when your plugin is activated, you can wrap this code in the [`register_activation_hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) hook.